# Permission denied (publickey) for private repo after adding SSH

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I've added SSH key successfully, I can clone other public repo using SSH but can't clone private repo! It shows this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause for this is that the ssh key or directory has the wrong permissions. The correct permission for the .ssh directory should be `700`, the public key should be `644` and the private key should be `600`.

To update the ssh key and directory, assuming that the `.ssh` directory is located at `~/.ssh`:

- `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`
- `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`
- `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub`

You might need to prefix these commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Would you please tell me, how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I added a step-by-step solution

Comment: Sorry for late replay, I've tried but not working, it shows the same message, also note that I'm using windows!